# RabbitMQ guarantee delivery to mirrored queue

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability, mirroring

Assume I have a mirrored queue deployed over multiple nodes (f.e. 1 master + 1 mirror). I can define the number of mirrors I want but is it possible to only accept a producer message when the message is stored at least on 2 queues (master + mirror). Otherwise it is still possible to loose a message when the master node fails before the message is mirrored.

So the mirroring activity should be part of the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Publisher Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms). When this is enabled, and your publisher has received confirmation, you can be certain that your message has been replicated to all queue mirrors.

Searching Google for `site:rabbitmq.com high availability` returns [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) which mentions Publisher Confirms [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html#confirms-transactions).

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly the explanation I was looking for. Don't know why I didn't find this myself. +1 for the NOTE.